# Trouble with Gson serializing an ArrayList of POJO's

Tags: java, json, serialization, arraylist, gson

I had been planning on using simpleXML for my serialization needs, but figured I would try JSON out, to learn something new.

This is the code I am using to try and serialize an ArrayList of test POJO's using Gson 1.7.1.

Note: I removed the Reader/Writers for a String "s" to simplify the code.

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class TestGsonSerialDeserialList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        //Make Serial 
        String s;
        List<TestObject> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<TestObject>() );
        list.add(new TestObject());
        list.add(new TestObject());

        s = gson.toJson(list, ArrayList.class);
        System.out.println(s);

        //Eat Serial
        List<TestObject> list2 = Collections.synchronizedList(gson.fromJson(s, ArrayList.class) );
        System.out.println(list2.get(0) );
        System.out.println(list2.get(1) );
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
[{"objectID":1,"i1":12345,"name":"abcdefg","s":["a","b","c"]},{"objectID":2,"i1":12345,"name":"abcdefg","s":["a","b","c"]}]
java.lang.Object@5c74c3aa
java.lang.Object@75d9fd51
```

To my newbie eyes this looks correct. Only, the DeSerialized list of objects contains basic Objects, rather then the TestObject's I serialized. Can anyone please explain to me what, if anything, I can do to make this work?

**EDIT:**

Corrected to test: Thanks to ColinD

```
package test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class TestGsonSerialDeserialList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("--- Serialize / Deserialize Started ---");
        String fileName = "json\\testList.json";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<List<TestObject>>(){}.getType();

        //Make Serial 
        Writer osWriter = new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        List<TestObject> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<TestObject>() );
        list.add(new TestObject());
        list.add(new TestObject());
        list.add(new TestObject());
        list.add(new TestObject());
        gson.toJson(list, osWriter);
        osWriter.close();


        //Eat Serial
        Reader isReader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream((fileName) ) );
        List<TestObject> list2 = Collections.synchronizedList(
            (List<TestObject>)gson.fromJson(isReader, listOfTestObject) 
        );
        isReader.close();
        System.out.println(list2.get(0) );
        System.out.println(list2.get(1) );
        System.out.println(list2.get(2) );
        System.out.println(list2.get(3) );
        System.out.println("--- Serialize / Deserialize Ended ---");
    }
}
```

output:

```
--- Serialize / Deserialize Started ---
ID#: 1, i1: 12345, name: abcdefg, s[]: [Ljava.lang.String;@95c083
ID#: 2, i1: 12345, name: abcdefg, s[]: [Ljava.lang.String;@6791d8c1
ID#: 3, i1: 12345, name: abcdefg, s[]: [Ljava.lang.String;@182d9c06
ID#: 4, i1: 12345, name: abcdefg, s[]: [Ljava.lang.String;@5a5e5a50
--- Serialize / Deserialize Ended ---
```

**EDIT2:**

I honestly don't know why, but when I replaced the simple String[] embedded in my TestObject with an ArrayList, it started serializing correctly.

```
--- Serialize / Deserialize Started ---
ID#: 1, i1: 12345, name: abcdefg, s[]: [a, b, c]
ID#: 2, i1: 12345, name: abcdefg, s[]: [a, b, c]
ID#: 3, i1: 12345, name: abcdefg, s[]: [a, b, c]
ID#: 4, i1: 12345, name: abcdefg, s[]: [a, b, c]
--- Serialize / Deserialize Ended ---
```

Comment: side note: Get rid of the Collections.synchronizedList() calls. You have a single-thread scenario, these calls only add overhead, nothing else

Comment: You are correct. They are there to make sure I can get it working. Once its working, I will remove them. This is purely for educational reasons. Once I get a good idea of Json serialization I will begin building for actual use.

Comment: Having said that, can anyone point me to where I can figure out how to get the Object embedded array to deserialize with a TypeToken?

Comment: Well, it seems that replacing the String[] with an ArrayList, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You need to give Gson information on the specific generic type of `List` you're using (or any generic type you use with it). Particularly when deserializing JSON, it needs that information to be able to determine what type of object it should deserialize each array element to.

```
Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<List<TestObject>>(){}.getType();
String s = gson.toJson(list, listOfTestObject);
List<TestObject> list2 = gson.fromJson(s, listOfTestObject);
```

This is documented in the [Gson user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples).

Comment: I was afraid that I was not seeing something obvious. I have never used Type's before, and was confused at its use. You just cleared it up for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I may likely have another question regarding serialization of a Queue soon! Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I was a bit quick there. It seems that I need to find a way to apply a TypeToken to the TestObject's String[].

Comment: @ColinD I can directly use this 'List<TestObject> list' to populate in android listview? custom adapter should implement serializable ? any help?

Comment: @ColinD What if `List<TestObject>` is nested in another class? How does the use of `Type` apply in that case to deserialize using something like `MyCustomClass obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyCustomClass.class)`

Comment: @raffian: Do you mean if `MyCustomClass` has a `List<TestObject>` field that needs to be deserialized? If so, there's no problem... Gson can see that the type of the field is `List<TestObject>` statically and deserialize the list based on that.

Comment: @ColinD Yes, that's what I mean, a nested `List<TestObjects>`. Does the same hold true for nested `HashMap<String,Object>`? I had some issues when deserializing `Boolean` and `Integer` values from the map, I suspect `Object` is the issue. I want to avoid boiler plate code to manually configure type transformers. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This answer fixed half of my problem. But I also had to flip my column from `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to `FetchType.EAGER` then my code started working.