# conversion of array list to json object string

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, playframework

I have a model class method which returns a list of objects which contains all the registered user details. I want to fetch the list resturned by all() method and convert the data into JSON object and pass it to the view like a string. How can I do this conversion of this array list to JSON object?

I was unable to do this by below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JsonNodeFactory jsonnode = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
ObjectNode result = new ObjectNode(jsonnode);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    json.put(list.get(i).fname, list.get(i));
    System.out.println(json.get("fname"));
}

@Entity
class Mydata extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long Id;
    public String fname;
    public String lname;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    /****************** READ/select OPERATION *****************/
    public static Finder < Long, Mydata > finder = new Finder(Long.class, Mydata.class);

    public static List < Mydata > all() {
        return finder.all();
    }
    public static void createuser(Mydata user) {
        user.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait wait wait; you are mixing Jackson and org.json here!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813434/trouble-with-gson-serializing-an-arraylist-of-pojos

Comment: [conversion of array list to json object string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylistmycustomclass-to-jsonarray/30193029#30193029

Answer (score 19):

To convert ArrayList to Json, just download Open Source json utility from:
http://json.org/java/ or Jar file from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

And just do:

```
JSONArray jsonAraay = new JSONArray(your_array_list);
```

That's it

Note: You should have setter/getter in your POJO/MODEL class to convert arraylist to json

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with org.json, use Jackson all the way:

```
// list is a List<MyData>
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final Map<String, MyData> map = new HashMap<>();
for (final MyData data: list)
    map.put(data.fname, data);
final JsonNode json = mapper.valueToTree(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use all sorts of third party libraries like others here have suggested, or just use Play's own simplified methods for this (found in `play.libs.Json`) which works with Jackson objects, but it is integrated into the framework and requires a lot less code to use, for example:

`JsonNode myJsonNode = Json.toJson(MyListObject);` which converts the List to a JsonNode object, then use something like `String jsonResult = Json.stringify(myJsonNode);` to convert it into a string representation.

If you are using the JSON in a template, don't forget to wrap it in something like `@Html(myJsonString)` so it will not escape anything.  Otherwise, if you are just outputting the pure JSON to the browser, a simple `return ok(jsonResult);` will work as Play will automatically set the content type.

Reference link: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/libs/Json.html

Comment: Hi Netizen, i am trying to pass the data from java method (in the form of json array string) to my view. So essentially i am looking for a "JAVA" function to convert List<MyData> list to json object array ....

Comment: What I posted should do it for you - it converts a Java List object to a JSON string, which is then interpreted in your template by the Javascript interpreter as a JSON array (as long as you did not escape anything like I showed).  You can put the resulting JSON data directly into the template or create an AJAX API to feed it as pure text like I showed above.  Either way, what I put above should work for you if I understand what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at this:
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#valueToString(java.lang.Object)

```
JSONObject.valueToString(<<your list of custom object>> OR <<objects>> OR <<map>>)
```

works just fine...there are some other methods on that lib, if you are interested....