# convert Arraylist into json

Tags: java, json, arraylist

please help how could we convert the below Arraylist method into Json

```
public ArrayList<String> helloName(String patentno)  {

    ArrayList<String> bibo = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int row = 2; row < rowsize; row++) {
        pno = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//*[@id='body']/table/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td"))
                .getText();
        bibo.add(pno);
    }
    return bibo;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: possible duplicate of [conversion of array list to json object string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359830/conversion-of-array-list-to-json-object-string)

Answer (score 9):

Use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) library for that. Here is the sample code

```
ArrayList<String> bibo = new ArrayList<String>();
bibo.add("obj1");
bibo.add("obj2");
bibo.add("obj3");
String json = new Gson().toJson(bibo);
```

And [this example](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples) from Gson User Guide to use it on collection

Answer (score 2):

use 
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();`

```
JsonArray myCustomArray = gson.toJsonTree(list).getAsJsonArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray**](http://jettison.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONArray.html) for the same ([**Download jar**](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.3.3/jettison-1.3.3.jar)).

Example Code :

```
   ArrayList bibo=new ArrayList();

   .....

  JSONArray ar=new JSONArray(bibo);
  String json= ar.toString();
```