# Cannot get response via jquery from controller to jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, httpresponse

I am sending a id to controller from dropdown(oncgange function). It is working fine. Now in controller after querying from database result is stored in arrylist. i have given returntype arrylist. is it ok or there is any error. please help. i just want to display another dropdown based selected value of first dropdown.
***Suppose i selected Fruit , so i want to populate this in jsp.***

```
<option value="mango">Mango</option>
<option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
```

**jsp**

```
         <script>
            function getScode()
            {
                var code = document.getElementById('code'),
                    code = code.value;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'scode.htm',
                    data: {
                        code: code
                    },
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#scode_data').html(html).show();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>

          Select Genre
            <select name="code" id="code"  onchange="getScode();">        
            <option value="1">Fruit</option>
            <option value="2">Game</option>              
            </select>
          Under that
         <div id="scode_data"></div>
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/scode", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ArrayList getScode(ModelMap modelMap, @RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code_val, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ClassNotFoundException { 

        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource = new dbconnection.connection().getConnection(dataSource);
        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM cat WHERE fcode='"+code_val+"'";
        srs = jt.queryForRowSet(sql);
        while (srs.next()) {
            pojo obj2 = new pojo();
            obj2.setScode(srs.getString("fcode"));
            obj2.setSname(srs.getString("fname"));
            arraylist.add(obj2);
        }

         return arraylist;
    }
```

[Image link of what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stYmS.png)

Comment: you'll have send the json version of the arraylist. And in the success function parse that json which you have received and append it to the another <select>.

Comment: i am now able to get data via ajax. But it shows ... arraylist data like ....  ** model.pojo@14e79b55model.pojo@46162020 **

Comment: Check what are you getting on success in the browser console. 
`success: function (html) {
 console.log(html);
 $('#scode_data').html(html).show(); 
}`
You should be getting array of object. Post the screenshot of that.

Comment: @SurajRoy As you have not converted the list to json you're getting the toString representation of the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801248/convert-arraylist-into-json This will help you

Comment: @SanjayRawat can not post screenshot ,,not have enough score

Comment: @SanjayRawat added an image link

Comment: As Obi Wan said, you haven't converted list to json. Try that and if you still have issue I'll try to answer.

Comment: fine,, now it is doing some work ,,  now its showing this =                                                              [{"scode":"1","sname":"mango"},{"scode":"2","sname":"pineapple"}] @SanjayRawat

Comment: i want to show this = <option value="mango">mango</option><option value="pineapple">pineapple</option> @SanjayRawat

Comment: fine,, now it is doing some work ,, now its showing this = [{"scode":"1","sname":"mango"},{"scode":"2","sname":"pineapple"}]  
     
i want to show this = <option value="mango">mango</option><option value="pineapple">pineapple</option>  @ObiWan-PallavJha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you've to convert the json string into option nodes. Below code would do the work:

```
success : function(result) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(result);

            var b = "";
            for(var x = 0; x<parsed.length ; x++){
                b = "<option value = '"+parsed["scode"]>+"'>"
                b = parsed["sname"] + "</option>";
                $("#__id of your select_").append(b);
                b = "";
            }
```

Comment: it displays ,,, UNDEFINED

Comment: @SurajRoy the append function should be called from the object of the new select you've created.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zL9lF.png  .................check thsi image .. i have tested with alert this shows as response

Comment: 2 field should come as result.. alert also shows 2 times,, so i think data is coming ,, but for some reason it undefined

Comment: i am thinking how will it access my arraylist.. should i add a modelmap and return modelmap object

Comment: No don't return model map. Comment what you're getting in the response in the success function.

Comment: check this image link ,,, tested with ** alert(b) ** it shows this >>> http://stack.imgur.com/zL9lF.png