# Java's arraylist to javascript's array not working

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, arraylist

Below is the code in my jsp file to convert Java's `ArrayList` to JavaScript's `Array`:

```
<% for(int k=0;k<listDate.size();k++){%>
    var temp =<%=listDate.get(k)%>
    dates[<%=k%>] = temp;
<%}%>
document.write(dates[0]); // it prints out a totally unrelated value which I have no idea what it is "1974".
```

Comment: what do you store in the `listDate`? What *should* be printed, what actually *gets* printed? How does the resulting javaScript code look like?

Comment: i found the solution: var temp ="<%=listDate.get(k)%>";

Comment: While, its better to create `JSONArray` on server-side then `parse` it in javascript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359830/conversion-of-array-list-to-json-object-string

Comment: Your code might be breaking, wrap your scriptlets in single / double quotes, if you want your current solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to give you a reference how you can update the code and used the scriptlet result --

```
<%

String hiddenResult = "";


// DO your business logic here and assign value to the  hiddenResult
<% for(int k=0;k<listDate.size();k++){%>
     hiddenResult = hiddenResult + listDate.get(k)+",";
     hiddenResult = hiddenResult.substring(0,hiddenResult.length()-1);  
%>

Assign the scriptlet result in the hidden field of the form and use that hidden field like this

<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInputResult" name="hiddenDDResult" value="<%=hiddenResult%>" />
<!--assign the value here in hidden field -->



function myFunction(){
    var arrayValue = document.getElementById("hiddenInputResult").value;
    // you can split by using arrayValue.split(","); to use

}
```