# Java JSON deserialize inheritance class

Tags: java, json, inheritance

I am using Gson to deserialize a class which is inherited from an abstract class.

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class Mammal {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Mammal {
    public void bark(){

    }
}

public class Cat extends Mammal{

    public void mew(){

    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Mammal dog = new Dog();
        String toGson = gson.toJson(dog);
        Mammal aDog = gson.fromJson(toGson, Mammal.class);
    }
}
```

An exception is thrown when I run it, can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line

```
Mammal aDog = gson.fromJson(toGson, Mammal.class);
```

you are trying to deserialize to instance of Mammal object, which cant be done because `Mammal` is abstract class which means it cant be instantiated.

You need either remove `abstract` keyword from `Mammal` class description or use non abstract class instead like `Dog.class`

```
Mammal aDog = gson.fromJson(toGson, Dog.class);
```

Comment: Thank you. Then if at runtime, I dont know what aDog's class is, I just know it is a subclass of Mammal, and I need to cast it to the right subclass, what should I do?

Comment: @user2716189 That is good question. You should ask it as separated thread, but before you do it check this [fragment of Gson tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types).

Comment: @user2716189  Also in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813490/1393766) author mention about using `listOfTestObject` while serializing and deserialiing collections of different objects.

Comment: @user2716189 `Then if at runtime, I dont know what aDog's class is` you always can use `getClass()` method to derermine real type of object. Java also have `instanceof` operator.

Comment: Thank you, that works, I parse the String to JsonObject and check its field value,then convert it to the right class