# Serializing class with multiple generics using GSON

Tags: android, serialization, gson

I've a data class containing two lists of generics:

```
data class Warehouse(
    val cars: MutableList<out Car>,
    val planes: MutableList<out Plane>,
)
```

For now, I tried to serialize my object using:

```
val warehouse = Warehouse(cars, planes)
val json = Gson().toJson(warehouse)
```

which gives me the following json:

```
{
    "cars": [
    {}
  ],
    "planes": [
    {}
  ],
}
```

If I serialize the cars using

```
val cars: MutableList<Car> = getCars()
val json = Gson().toJson(cars)
```

everything works as intended i.e. the json contains the right informations.

According to the documentation, an object of a known type can contain any field of generic type:

```
 /**
   * This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json representation.
   * This method should be used when the specified object is not a generic type. This method uses
   * {@link Class#getClass()} to get the type for the specified object, but the
   * {@code getClass()} loses the generic type information because of the Type Erasure feature
   * of Java. Note that this method works fine if the any of the object fields are of generic type,
   * just the object itself should not be of a generic type. If the object is of generic type, use
   * {@link #toJson(Object, Type)} instead. If you want to write out the object to a
   * {@link Writer}, use {@link #toJson(Object, Appendable)} instead.
   *
   * @param src the object for which Json representation is to be created setting for Gson
   * @return Json representation of {@code src}.
   */
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think this response should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813490/10411926

Comment: @lukasinios it won't work since my root object is not a generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to register the different type adapter manually:

```
val json = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Car::class.java, CarSerializer())
            .registerTypeAdapter(Plane::class.java, PlaneSerializer())
            .create()
            .toJson(data)
```

with `CarSerializer` defined as:

```
class CarSerializer : JsonSerializer<Car> {

    override fun serialize(src: Car, typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement {
        return when (src) {
            is Ferrari -> context.serialize(src, Ferrari::class.java)
            is Mercedes -> context.serialize(src, Mercedes::class.java)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unspecified class serializer for ${src.javaClass.name}")
        }
    }
}
```

The `PlaneSerializer` is defined the same way.