# GSON generics serialization

Tags: java, generics, serialization, types, gson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [deserializing generics with gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364392/deserializing-generics-with-gson)

So I need to do:

```
Type fluentType = new TypeToken<BruteForceFluentImpl<GtlDigestor.Data>>() {}.getType();
```

instead of

```
Type fluentType = new TypeToken<Fluent<T>>() {}.getType(); // <-- i want to be able to do something like this.

String json = gson.toJson(fluent, fluentType);
```

This means that every time I have to specify a different type parameter for the Fluent class, I need to change my code in order to specify it. Right now, the type parameter is `GtlDigestor.Data`.

How do I do this? (the second line of code won't work)

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364392/deserializing-generics-with-gson ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Gson the actual parameterized type (e.g. `BruteForceFluentImpl<GtlDigestor.Data>`, including the actual runtime raw type and the actual type parameter value) at runtime, because Gson needs to save this information.

Using `TypeToken` is the easiest way to get a `Type`, but to use it you must hard-code the exact type in the source (no type parameters like `T`). If you would like to put the code in a method that will be re-used with different types, then perhaps this method should accept the `Type` as a parameter, which the caller needs to pass in. The type can then be hard-coded at the caller's location, each of which presumably only uses a fixed type.

Or, if you need to generate the `Type` completely dynamically at runtime based on the raw type and type parameters, see my answer for the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111899/).